# Scraping with beautifulsoup and python. Solving how to see the bidders name in eBay

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I run a store on eBay and I want to scrape all the bidders that participate in my auctions. I'm able to see

1. The Bid amount
2. Time of bid

However, I cannot scrape

1. Bidders name
2. Bidders Location

The picture will show an HTML doc
[Table that shows the bidders participating in one of my auctions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUoTm.png)

[Here's the image of the codes that I'm running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjdeb.jpg)

***I'm using jupyter notebook to run my codes. This is the code that I use***

```
'results = soup.find('table', {'class':'app-bid-history__table'}).find('tbody').find_all('span')'
```

> [Highest Bidderprivate listing - bidders' identities protected,
> Highest Bidderprivate listing - bidders' identities protected,
> Highest Bidder,
> $47.00,
> $47.00,
> 27 Jul 2021 at 6:59:53pm PDT,
> 27 Jul 2021 at 6:59:53pm PDT,

As you can see, the Bidder's name and location do not show, but you are able to see it in the HTML doc. What code do I need to run?

Answer (score 2):

1. **You may need to check your parser:** if you are using `'lxml'`, try `'Html.parser'` or `'html5lib'` to see if any of those work.

   e.g.
   `soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')`
2. **Append another span:** From the image, it seems that all relevant values are a `<span>` inside of another `<span>`. Append before the `<span>` and then `find_all <span>`.

   e.g. `.find('span')find_all('span')`
3. If these don't work, **you may need to search the `<div>` by class seperately**:

   Define `.find('tbody')` as a seperate value, then try out `x = tbody.find('div', {'class':'textual-display-item'})` and then `y = x.find_all('span')`.

Comment: I insert another image of the codes that I am running, is this what you meant when append spans?

Comment: 'x = results.find('div',{'class' : 'textual-display-item'})'
'y = x.find_all('span')'

here's what shows, I think I  got it.

[<span><!--F#10--><span class="cc-text-spans--BOLD"><span class="clipped">Highest Bidder</span>private listing - bidders' identities protected</span><!--F/--></span>,
 <span class="cc-text-spans--BOLD"><span class="clipped">Highest Bidder</span>private listing - bidders' identities protected</span>,
 <span class="clipped">Highest Bidder</span>]